# Running valgrind on project compiled with autotools outputs multiple heap summaries

Tags: c, valgrind, autotools, automake, libtool

I'm compiling a project with automake, but when attempting to run valgrind on the resulting executable, it does not behave as expected, appearing to run 8 times before actually executing the code that I want to check, and the heap summary for that piece of code is not displayed at all:

```
==4601== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4601== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.                                                                                            
==4601== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info                                                                                          
==4601== Command: ./launcher -g ../data/params.txt                                                                                                                  
==4601==                                                                                                                                                            
==4605==                                                                                                                                                            
==4605== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4605==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4605==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4605==                                                                                                                                                            
==4605== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4605==                                                                                                                                                            
==4605== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4605== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
==4604==                                                                                                                                                            
==4604== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4604==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4604==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4604==                                                                                                                                                            
==4604== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4604==                                                                                                                                                            
==4604== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4604== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
==4606==                                                                                                                                                            
==4606== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4606==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4606==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4606==                                                                                                                                                            
==4606== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4606==                                                                                                                                                            
==4606== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4606== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
==4608==                                                                                                                                                            
==4608== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4608==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4608==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4608==                                                                                                                                                            
==4608== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4608==                                                                                                                                                            
==4608== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4608== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
==4607==                                                                                                                                                            
==4607== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4607==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4607==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4607==                                                                                                                                                            
==4607== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4607==                                                                                                                                                            
==4607== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4607== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
==4610==                                                                                                                                                            
==4610== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4610==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4610==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4610==                                                                                                                                                            
==4610== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4610==                                                                                                                                                            
==4610== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4610== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
==4613==                                                                                                                                                            
==4613== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4613==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4613==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4613==                                                                                                                                                            
==4613== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4613==                                                                                                                                                            
==4613== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4613== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
==4614==                                                                                                                                                            
==4614== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                              
==4614==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                    
==4614==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                   
==4614==                                                                                                                                                            
==4614== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                        
==4614==                                                                                                                                                            
==4614== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                               
==4614== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)                                                                                             
[Program output appears here, nothing appears afterwards]
```

Previously, when compiling with a standard makefile there were no such issues and valgrind would display exactly what I expected. The `makefile.am` that I'm using for compiling the directory looks like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfile_util.la libmath_util.la libgeneral_util.la libparamlist.la
libfile_util_la_SOURCES = file_util.c file_util.h
libmath_util_la_SOURCES = math_util.c math_util.h
libgeneral_util_la_SOURCES = general_util.c general_util.h
libparamlist_la_SOURCES = paramlist.c paramlist.h

bin_PROGRAMS = launcher
generator_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/muParser
generator_SOURCES = generator.c generator.h
estimator_SOURCES = estimator.c estimator.h
estimator_iwls_SOURCES = estimator_IWLS.c estimator.h
estimator_piecewise_SOURCES = estimator_IWLS.c estimator_piecewise.c estimator.h
estimator_baseline_SOURCES = estimator_IWLS.c estimator_piecewise.c estimator_baseline.c estimator.h
launcher_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/muParser
launcher_SOURCES = launcher.c generator.c estimator.c estimator.h generator.h
generator_LDADD = libfile_util.la libmath_util.la libgeneral_util.la libparamlist.la
launcher_LDADD = libfile_util.la libmath_util.la libgeneral_util.la libparamlist.la
estimator_iwls_LDADD = libfile_util.la libmath_util.la libgeneral_util.la libparamlist.la
estimator_piecewise_LDADD = libfile_util.la libmath_util.la libgeneral_util.la libparamlist.la
estimator_baseline_LDADD = libfile_util.la libmath_util.la libgeneral_util.la libparamlist.la
```

Is this issue something to do with the way that automake compiles the files? If so, what am I doing wrong in the makefile?

Comment: I think if you check, the "launcher" binary that you made is actually a shell script that runs the binary you wanted to make in the first place.  I can't remember the magic incantation to make libtool stop doing this.  It has something to do with running the binary "uninstalled".  Hopefully this points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `launcher` is using a libtool library, the file that is in your build directory is just a shell script that setups the necessary environment variables to run the real binary (usually hidden in `.libs/`).  Running valgrind on that script will debug the shell executing the script, not your real binary.

The proper way to execute any command like `valgrind` or `gdb` on a libtool binary is via the `libtool` command:

```
libtool --mode=execute valgrind ./launcher -g ../data/params.txt
```

You may even abbreviate it as:

```
libtool e valgrind ./launcher -g ../data/params.txt
```

This will work regardless of how `launcher` was compiled.

The relevant libtool documentation is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Debugging-executables.html#Debugging-executables).

Comment: This is a far better solution than the other option.